# How can I update copies of the same razor component separately?

Tags: c#, svg, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have several of the same Component added on a page.
When I update any of the components the view does not reflect the change for that component
If I update the first component all the other components reflect the same change.
I also have a Label to indicate the changing value. the Label indicates different values for each component yet the view only indicates the changes made to the fist component and is reflected to all the other components.
Can some one point out my issue and maybe provide an example on how to correct it.
I have tried different variations of java script (maybe not correctly) however I am thinking I shouldn't need anything ales at it does work just not as expected.
Thank you in advance.

here you can see the update is applied but using only the info from the first(tiny) component
[image]

Main Page

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; margin:200px">
            <TestComponent ID="Test1" Offset2="@MyOffset1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <TestComponent ID="Test2" Offset2="@MyOffset2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="margin: 50px">
            <TestComponent ID="Test3" Offset2="@MyOffset3"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 200px">
            <TestComponent ID="Test4" Offset2="@MyOffset4"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{

    [Inject]
    public ComponentTimer T { get; set; }
    public double MyOffset1 { get; set; }
    public double MyOffset2 { get; set; }
    public double MyOffset3 { get; set; }
    public double MyOffset4 { get; set; }
    private const double _timeInterval = 3000;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await StartTimer();
    }

    private Task StartTimer()
    {
        T.SetTimer(_timeInterval, true);
        T.Onelapsed +=
            async delegate
            {
                await StartAsync();
            };
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task StartAsync()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int r = 1; r < 5; r++)
        {
            double ra = rand.NextDouble();
            switch (r)
            {
                case 1:
                    MyOffset1 = ra;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    MyOffset2 = ra;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    MyOffset3 = ra;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    MyOffset4 = ra;
                    break;
            }
            if (r >= 4)
            {
                StateHasChanged();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Component

```
<h3>TestComponent</h3>
<label style="color: red; font-size: 50px">@Offset2</label>
<svg width="auto" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="dialColorScale">
            <stop style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="0"
                  id="stop1" />
            <stop style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="@Offset2"
                  id="stop2" />
            <stop style="stop-color:#ff6600;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="0.53708327"
                  id="stop3" />
            <stop style="stop-color:#ffff00;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="0.62770826"
                  id="stop4" />
            <stop style="stop-color:#ffff00;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="0.80468744"
                  id="stop5" />
            <stop style="stop-color:#00ff00;stop-opacity:1"
                  offset="1"
                  id="stop6" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g class="GaugeColorScale">
        <path id="path6115"
              fill="url(#dialColorScale)"
              d="m 400.00009,256.2508 a 299.44714,296.14774 0 0 0 -299.44726,296.14844 299.44714,296.14774 0 0 0 0.0937,2.7461 h 74.83593 a 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 -0.0684,-1.92188 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 2.28711,-31.60937 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 6.81055,-30.9668 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.19726,-29.69141 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 15.35743,-27.81445 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 19.20312,-25.36914 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 22.6582,-22.4082 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 25.65235,-18.99219 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 28.125,-15.1875 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 30.02148,-11.07422 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 31.3125,-6.73633 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 31.96094,-2.26172 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.375,0.28516 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.3457,0.85547 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.28907,1.42187 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.19921,1.98438 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 11.08399,2.54492 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 10.93945,3.0957 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 10.76758,3.63867 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 10.56641,4.17579 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 10.33984,4.69726 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 10.08594,5.21094 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 9.80664,5.70898 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 9.5,6.19141 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 9.17186,6.66211 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 8.81836,7.11133 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 8.44336,7.54297 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 8.04689,7.95703 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 7.62694,8.35156 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 7.19142,8.7207 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 6.73436,9.07031 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 6.26172,9.39649 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 5.77148,9.69727 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 5.26955,9.9746 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 4.75,10.22657 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 4.22069,10.45117 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 3.6797,10.64844 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 3.13086,10.81836 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 2.57225,10.96289 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 2.00781,11.07617 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 1.4375,11.16211 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 0.86329,11.22265 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 0.28906,11.24805 224.58543,222.11078 0 0 1 -0.0684,1.92188 h 74.83594 a 299.44714,296.14774 0 0 0 0.0937,-2.7461 A 299.44714,296.14774 0 0 0 399.9999,256.2508 Z" />

    </g>
</svg>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public double Offset2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is using an HTML id, in `<linearGradient id="dialColorScale">`

So as far as the browser can see you have 4 elements with the same #id. Last one wins.

Luckily you also have your own ID, so make it:

```
<linearGradient id="@("dialColorScale"+ID)" >
```

and

```
fill="url(#@("dialColorScale"+ID))"
```